# How to approximate big composite number factors?

Tags: primes, factoring

There is a big 1024-bits number A that was obtained by multiplying two numbers B and C.Are there any ways to get first numerical digits of these numbers?

How example:

```
A(4.65467...e+1024) = B(2.25351...e+512) x C(2.62568...e+256)
```

I want to receive `2.25` and `2.62` accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.  The [factoring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) is believed to be hard.  Without knowing the full factorization, for any guess at the top digits of B you can reconstruct a set of top digits of C that would be consistent with that.